# What is the point of declaring variables without assignment?

Tags: javascript

I'm studying some CreateJS samples and in one of them I've seen this and I'm wondering what use it's for

```
(function() {
    var c = createjs;
    var a = function(blabla) {
        this.blabla = blabla;

    var p = Game.prototype;
    p.a;
    p.b;
    p.c;
    p.d;
    /*
    ... 15 variables like that ...
    */
    p.init = function(param) {
        /* blabla */
    }
    /*
    ...
    long code after that
    ...
    */
})();
```

It's on the github samples, in the `/createjs/sandbox-master/PlanetaryGary` directory, it's the file `js/Game.js`

Comment: There aren't any variables being declared without assignment there. (There are expressions consisting of nothing but a mention of a property on an object and they appear utterly pointless).

Comment: it is probably due to performance also. just like creating an array with a defined length is much faster than dynamically changing/adding things to the array. so the program kinda knows what its dealing with

Comment: That will have absolutely no effect on performance.

Comment: If this example is on github (or any repo), reading the commits may give you the anwser.

Comment: are you sure? i can imagine it is more performant for the garbage collector

Comment: Most likely it is completely optimized away, meaning zero performance impact.

Comment: @Alex absolutely not. Those statements have no purpose. Mentioning an undefined property of an object does not affect the object at all.

Comment: If you would identify exactly what sample code you're looking at, you'll be far more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the original author of the code in question. This pattern comes down to the simple philosophy that good code is self-documenting.

It's worth a quick mention for those coming into this blind that those properties are not actually named a,b,c, etc. It's also worth mentioning that they are usually assigned a default value (though not in this particular case).

The up-front variable declarations explicitly define the fields that will be associated with the "class". This allows a developer to scan from the top down, and establish a mental model of the data the class operates on prior to looking at the methods that operate on it.

It provides a convenient, contextual place to hook doc comments, though the referenced code is not documented.

```
/**
 * Docs for firstName here.
 **/
p.firstName = "default";

/**
 * lastName docs.
 **/
p.lastName = "default";
```

Lastly, I've found it encourages a more thoughtful approach to data and documentation. The act of defining a new property becomes an opportunity to view the existing properties and evaluate the necessity of the new field. I've seen a lot of bugs and poor code result from devs appending properties to classes willy-nilly.

It's also a lot harder to forget to document new properties (and much easier to quickly spot undocumented properties) when you're explicitly defining them in a dedicated area of your code.

Comment: I perfectly understand your point of view, and it's quite a good idea. It's the **`though not in this particular case`** and the **`though the referenced code is not documented`** that changes everything... maybe just one line of comment explaining what these declaration are for, or just saying "to be documented" should be enough for beginners like me. Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: Frankly, this seems like an odd approach to documentation to me, but I guess it's better than nothing. If you want to document something, then document it, rather than putting arcane field references which don't do anything in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing too many specifics about the alphabetical data members of some `Game` object, mentioning `p.a`, `p.b`, etc. in the way that you have shown is a good way to expose exactly how the variable `p` is structured.

In the control flow of the code snippet you've shared, we can see exactly what fields the variable `p` has before performing any initialization or other operations on it.

Comment: This would imply a lot of maintainance. E.g. adding any variable would imply declaring it here too too keep everything homogeneous.

Comment: It'd be a similar level of maintenance to object-oriented programming languages, in that this section of code can serve as a "header" for how ```p``` is to be used.

Comment: @OlivierPons: The point is to remember doing the maintenance. You can do the exact same thing with comments except that we all know developers don't update comments ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the object `p` has getters assigned to it with side effects:

```
Object.defineProperty(p, 'a', { get: function() {
  window.universalConstant = 42;
  return p._a;
});
```

Possible, but unlikely. Probably it's a misguided attempt at documentation as @PaulD suggests.

Comment: This is the only actually interesting possibility, but I agree that it's highly unlikely to be what's going on in that code.